# post-hoc test on mixed-effects model

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, post-hoc

I have an experiment with bacteria for which I measured growth curves of several bacterial clones in two different types of media (treat). I then extracted several growth parameters from the curves and am analysing one of these: lag phase (lambda). clone has 13 levels and treat has 2 levels.  I now want to know, for each clone, if my lambda is different between the two treatments.

As I carried multiple non-independent replicates for each clone, I created a mixed effects model of the following form

```
m1<-lme(lambda~treat*clone,random=~1|replicate)
```

As the interaction is significant, I used lsmeans to try to get the comparisons between the two treatments for the different clones. Below is the code I used for the function and the output. Now there are two things puzzling me: 1) why is lsmeans unable to estimate the df?; 2) Why is the SE the same across most of the different clones?

```
lsmeans(m1,pairwise~treat|clone,adjust="tukey")



$`treat:clone lsmeans`
   treat clone    lsmean       SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
     glu     1  274.5716 40.05260 NA  196.0700  353.0733
 glu.ALA     1  316.6030 40.05260 NA  238.1014  395.1047
     glu    11  628.6852 40.05260 NA  550.1835  707.1868
 glu.ALA    11  301.2156 40.05260 NA  222.7139  379.7172
     glu    19  586.9249 40.05260 NA  508.4232  665.4265
 glu.ALA    19  622.3766 40.05260 NA  543.8749  700.8782
     glu    26  712.6377 40.05260 NA  634.1360  791.1393
 glu.ALA    26  350.8608 40.05260 NA  272.3592  429.3625
     glu    28  491.2373 40.05260 NA  412.7357  569.7390
 glu.ALA    28  314.1701 40.05260 NA  235.6685  392.6718
     glu    31  559.2341 40.05260 NA  480.7325  637.7358
 glu.ALA    31  452.9919 40.05260 NA  374.4902  531.4935
     glu    40  569.0526 40.05260 NA  490.5509  647.5542
 glu.ALA    40  592.2210 40.05260 NA  513.7194  670.7227
     glu    41  430.7679 40.05260 NA  352.2663  509.2696
 glu.ALA    41  456.9167 40.05260 NA  378.4150  535.4183
     glu    48  739.8913 40.05260 NA  661.3896  818.3929
 glu.ALA    48  709.2002 40.05260 NA  630.6985  787.7018
     glu    51  388.9805 40.05260 NA  310.4788  467.4821
 glu.ALA    51  395.3881 40.05260 NA  316.8865  473.8898
     glu    52  499.6519 40.05260 NA  421.1502  578.1535
 glu.ALA    52  471.2882 43.87542 NA  385.2940  557.2824
     glu    61 1200.5866 40.05260 NA 1122.0850 1279.0883
 glu.ALA    61  817.7402 40.05260 NA  739.2385  896.2418
     glu   Anc  262.7183 25.33149 NA  213.0695  312.3671
 glu.ALA   Anc  302.1657 26.22058 NA  250.7743  353.5571

$`treat:clone pairwise differences`
                      estimate       SE df  z.ratio p.value
glu - glu.ALA | 1   -42.031407 56.64292 NA -0.74204 0.45808
glu - glu.ALA | 11  327.469629 56.64292 NA  5.78130 0.00000
glu - glu.ALA | 19  -35.451732 56.64292 NA -0.62588 0.53141
glu - glu.ALA | 26  361.776858 56.64292 NA  6.38697 0.00000
glu - glu.ALA | 28  177.067207 56.64292 NA  3.12603 0.00178
glu - glu.ALA | 31  106.242222 56.64292 NA  1.87565 0.06073
glu - glu.ALA | 40  -23.168464 56.64292 NA -0.40903 0.68253
glu - glu.ALA | 41  -26.148743 56.64292 NA -0.46164 0.64435
glu - glu.ALA | 48   30.691103 56.64292 NA  0.54183 0.58795
glu - glu.ALA | 51   -6.407644 56.64292 NA -0.11312 0.90994
glu - glu.ALA | 52   28.363655 59.40760 NA  0.47744 0.63306
glu - glu.ALA | 61  382.846452 56.64292 NA  6.75895 0.00000
glu - glu.ALA | Anc -39.447421 36.45824 NA -1.08199 0.27928
    p values are adjusted using the tukey method for 2 means
```